# jQuery : find tags within the string which contain text

Tags: jquery, regex, search, filter

I have a variable, which stores table rows with some content. I would like to search that string for a specific term using the %%LIKE%% approach and if found add this html row to a new variable containing filtered rows only.
If possible, I would like the search to be case insensitive.

So far I have the following, which doesn't seem to work:

```
// current list
var thisBlock = '<tr><td>Some content</td></tr><tr><td>Some other content</td></tr><tr><td>Even more content</td></tr>';

// new list
var thisList;

// phrase to be found
var thisValue = 'Some';

// filter
var thisItems = $(thisBlock).find("tr:contains('" + thisValue + "')");

// loop to append the found rows
if (thisItems !== '' && typeof thisItems !== 'undefined') {
    $.each(thisItems, function() {
        thisList += $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    });
}
```

The problem seem to be with the filter part and I cannot figure out how to do it any other way.

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not that familiar with regular expressions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var thisItems = $('<table>'+thisBlock+'</table>').find("tr:contains('" + thisValue + "')");
```

Without the wrapping table tags i dont think jQuery will see it as a valid tag, as it has no root node.

UPDATE: The following code is working to add each matching row to the table #outTab, can you work with that to get to where you would like?

```
<table id="outTab"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
// current list
var thisBlock = '<table><tr><td>Some content</td></tr><tr><td>Some other content</td></tr><tr><td>Even more content</td></tr></table>';

// new list
var thisList;

// phrase to be found
var thisValue = 'Some';

// filter
var thisItems = $(thisBlock).find("tr:contains('" + thisValue + "')");

// loop to append the found rows
if (thisItems !== '' && typeof thisItems !== 'undefined') {
    $.each(thisItems, function(){
        console.log( this );
        $('#outTab').append(this);
    });
    console.log(thisItems);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the result?

Comment: The result is to be displayed inside of the table tbody tag

Comment: I need the content of the table to be replaced rather than appending the elements one by one.

Comment: It works with just adding the table tags around the block - it was something different in my code that didn't allow the code to be executed and it was outside of this code. Thanks for you help.